C++ why need weak_ptr when we have shared_ptr use_count()?
Asking a dumb question. From what I understand one usage of weak_ptr is to check the count status of shared pointer on an object. Couldn't we just use the shared_ptr use_count() to get this info. If so why need weak_ptr?
As an example:
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    shared_ptr<int> a(new int(10));
    weak_ptr<int> wa(a);
    a.reset();
    assert(a.use_count() == 0); // clause 1 - good. indicate no binding objects
    assert(wa.lock() == nullptr); // clause 2 - good. same as above

    return 0;

}


Clause 1 & 2 produces identical results.
So why need weak_ptr (putting aside thread safety) to test for null binding objects when shared_ptr.use_count() can do the job?
Thanks.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

No, no we cannot.
The idea of weak_ptr is we want to have a reference to something but not keep it alive ourselves; that is when the strong references go away, so does the object; and when we resolve the weak pointer we get a null back.
One example of a weak_ptr might be in a binary tree; suppose every node needs a reference to its parent node. If you used shared_ptr to reference the parent node you would have a cycle which results in a memory leak, but the weak_ptr on the parent node doesn't.
There are other uses for weak pointers where you can have a reference to some large object from a place unrelated to its actual lifetime; but constructing a small easy to understand example is not trivial.

Neither of shared_ptr and weak_ptr makes sense in a tree. I imagine the most fitting place to use them is when different references to the same object are unaware of each other, and thus have no idea when the object dies. Something like entity component systems.

weak_ptr has its usage in such libraries like boost::signal2 -- where we have callbacks that can loose its target object -- but it is obvious they need a way to check, internally, if the object is still alive or not

@Joshua .. see my comment above responding to PiotrNycz2

@yapkm01: Beware the thread race. The idiom you describe here would be very dangerous should the tree be accessed by multiple readers in different threads. weak_ptr has native ability to protect the thread race.

@Joshua i hear ya. My point is using shared_ptr.use_count() == 0 will do the same job of checking for null pointed object, in place of weak_ptr.lock() == null. Thoughts?

@yapkm01: Doesn't work. What happens if shared_ptr.use_count() goes to zero in the next instruction after use_count() returns? If you say copy the shared_ptr first, you merely have a different problem. Copying a shared_ptr while another thread is calling release() and that release() would set it to zero is not thread safe.

@Joshua if shared_ptr.use_count() goes to 0 in the next instruction, wouldn't weak_ptr.lock() reflect that as well in place of former? Also  if shared_ptr.use_count() is not thread safe what makes weak_ptr.lock() is?

@yapkm01: Because weak_ptr contains a working implementation. It's not if (use_count() > 0) it's a slower algorithm that is thread safe instead wrapped up inside it.

@Joshua I think i see the light now. Like you said using shared_ptr.use_count() does not reflect correctly the state of it after next instruction example when you do another copy it changes the count. So by using weak_ptr this practically confirm the count as it is at that time of period without creating another shared_ptr which will change the count again. Let me know if i got this right.


From what I understand one usage of weak_ptr is to check the count status of shared pointer on an object.

This is not a common use, in part because it is gratuitously complicated. If you have a shared_ptr and want to know if its use count is zero, you can get that information directly from the shared_ptr. There is no need to construct a weak_ptr for this task.
In fact, constructing a weak_ptr is typically pointless unless it has a different lifetime than the shared_ptr from which it is constructed. It's only when the source shared_ptr is not accessible that a weak_ptr has value. At which point, there is no question that the weak_ptr is needed.

So why need weak_ptr (putting aside thread safety) to test for null binding objects when shared_ptr.use_count() can do the job?

If you have a shared_ptr available, you do not need a weak_ptr to the same object. But do not use use_count to check the status of the pointer (or for anything other than debugging). Instead, use get or just use the shared_ptr in a boolean context. That is, given shared_ptr<int> a; one can test the "count status" simply by if (a), where truth means a manages an object / has a use count greater than zero, and falsity means a does not manage an object / has a use count of zero.† (Some people prefer if (a != nullptr) for greater clarity.)
To put it in terms of your example code:
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> a(new int(10));
    a.reset();
    assert(!a); // clause 3 - good. indicate no binding objects
}

† To be pedantic, there is a pathological case where a shared pointer could be non-null yet not manage an object. However, this results from (mis-)use of the aliasing constructor, not reset(). The aliasing constructor is an advanced topic, so let's skip it here.

let me think through your answer here.
